# How do I profile my Ruby test suite in aggregate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, testing, profiling

The usual sob story: my tests are running slowly.

My first thought was to profile the whole test suite to look for obvious wins (stubbing out network access or caches), so I added a ruby-prof task:

```
RubyProf::ProfileTask.new(:units) do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList[RAILS_ROOT + '/test/unit/**/*_test.rb']
  t.output_dir = Dir.tmpdir
  t.printer = :graph
  t.min_percent = 1
end
```

Unfortunately, this profiles each test individually. Is there a way to get an aggregate over all of those test classes?

Comment: Have you tried just running `ruby-prof test_suite_name.rb` without adding any ruby-prof specific code to your tests?

Comment: Actually, I hadn't considered making an actual test suite. That might work!

Comment: In my Plain Old Ruby Object project, creating a test suite is easy. Just have one file `require` all the other files (or files that `require` other files). However, I don't know if this'll play nice with Rails' magic.

Comment: There's actually not all that much magic in Rails testing. This worked quite well. Will gladly accept if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `ruby-prof test_suite_name.rb`. You don't even need to add any ruby-prof specific code to your tests.

Answer (score 1):

There are [plans](http://lists.zenspider.com/pipermail/ruby/2010-October/005343.html) to add benchmarking to minitest.